# How to upload songs to spotify using python?

Tags: python, spotipy

I am trying to figure out how to upload songs to Spotify using python. I know that it is possible to upload local mp3 files to spotify, and then take them everywhere. Is this not supported by any python spotify api? I have looked at them all and can't seem to find any feature like this one. In particular, with spotipy api. I would ask them directly but they said for questions to post on stack overflow.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are right, there is no support to upload personal library via API at this moment. Spotify mentions this in the [limitation](https://developer.spotify.com/documentation/general/guides/local-files-spotify-playlists/).

> It is not currently possible to add local files to playlists using the
>   Web API, but they can be reordered or removed.

It is also unlikely happening in the future. Hope this helps.